Incorrect timezone setting on Heroku
2024-04-12T19:34:05.205212+00:00 app[web.1]: django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2024-04-12T19:34:05.205212+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
2024-04-12T19:34:05.205212+00:00 app[web.1]: configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2024-04-12T19:34:05.205212+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 89, in __getattr__   
2024-04-12T19:34:05.205212+00:00 app[web.1]: self._setup(name)
2024-04-12T19:34:05.205213+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 76, in _setup        
2024-04-12T19:34:05.205213+00:00 app[web.1]: self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2024-04-12T19:34:05.205213+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 225, in __init__     
2024-04-12T19:34:05.205213+00:00 app[web.1]: raise ValueError("Incorrect timezone setting: %s" % self.TIME_ZONE)
2024-04-12T19:34:05.205213+00:00 app[web.1]: ValueError: Incorrect timezone setting: America/Sao_paulo
2024-04-12T19:34:05.205357+00:00 app[web.1]: [2024-04-12 19:34:05 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2024-04-12T19:34:05.209935+00:00 app[web.1]: [2024-04-12 19:34:05 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2024-04-12T19:34:05.209937+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-04-12T19:34:05.209937+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 609, in spawn_worker     
2024-04-12T19:34:05.209938+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2024-04-12T19:34:05.209938+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2024-04-12T19:34:05.209939+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2024-04-12T19:34:05.209939+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi   
2024-04-12T19:34:05.209940+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2024-04-12T19:34:05.209940+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2024-04-12T19:34:05.209940+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2024-04-12T19:34:05.209941+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2024-04-12T19:34:05.209941+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2024-04-12T19:34:05.209941+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp  
2024-04-12T19:34:05.209941+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2024-04-12T19:34:05.209941+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 371, in import_app
2024-04-12T19:34:05.209942+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2024-04-12T19:34:05.209943+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2024-04-12T19:34:05.209943+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2024-04-12T19:34:05.209943+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
2024-04-12T19:34:05.209944+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
2024-04-12T19:34:05.209944+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2024-04-12T19:34:05.209944+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
2024-04-12T19:34:05.209944+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
2024-04-12T19:34:05.209945+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
2024-04-12T19:34:05.209945+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/nexus/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2024-04-12T19:34:05.209945+00:00 app[web.1]: application = get_wsgi_application()
2024-04-12T19:34:05.209945+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2024-04-12T19:34:05.209946+00:00 app[web.1]: django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2024-04-12T19:34:05.209946+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
2024-04-12T19:34:05.209946+00:00 app[web.1]: configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2024-04-12T19:34:05.209947+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 89, in __getattr__
2024-04-12T19:34:05.209947+00:00 app[web.1]: self._setup(name)
2024-04-12T19:34:05.209947+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 76, in _setup
2024-04-12T19:34:05.209947+00:00 app[web.1]: self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2024-04-12T19:34:05.209947+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 225, in __init__
2024-04-12T19:34:05.209948+00:00 app[web.1]: raise ValueError("Incorrect timezone setting: %s" % self.TIME_ZONE)
2024-04-12T19:34:05.209948+00:00 app[web.1]: ValueError: Incorrect timezone setting: America/Sao_paulo
2024-04-12T19:34:05.209949+00:00 app[web.1]: [2024-04-12 19:34:05 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2024-04-12T19:34:05.229481+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2024-04-12T19:34:05.268788+00:00 app[web.1]: [2024-04-12 19:34:05 +0000] [2] [ERROR] Worker (pid:10) exited with code 3
2024-04-12T19:34:05.273254+00:00 app[web.1]: [2024-04-12 19:34:05 +0000] [2] [ERROR] Worker (pid:9) exited with code 3
2024-04-12T19:34:05.273328+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-04-12T19:34:05.273343+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 209, in run
2024-04-12T19:34:05.273591+00:00 app[web.1]: self.sleep()
2024-04-12T19:34:05.273602+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 360, in sleep
2024-04-12T19:34:05.273708+00:00 app[web.1]: ready = select.select([self.PIPE[0]], [], [], 1.0)
2024-04-12T19:34:05.273718+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
2024-04-12T19:34:05.273794+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
2024-04-12T19:34:05.273804+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 530, in reap_workers
2024-04-12T19:34:05.273933+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2024-04-12T19:34:05.273998+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2024-04-12T19:34:05.274002+00:00 app[web.1]:
2024-04-12T19:34:05.274002+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2024-04-12T19:34:05.274002+00:00 app[web.1]:
2024-04-12T19:34:05.274012+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-04-12T19:34:05.274022+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 8, in <module>
2024-04-12T19:34:05.274104+00:00 app[web.1]: sys.exit(run())
2024-04-12T19:34:05.274114+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 67, in run
2024-04-12T19:34:05.274199+00:00 app[web.1]: WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
2024-04-12T19:34:05.274210+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 236, in run
2024-04-12T19:34:05.274305+00:00 app[web.1]: super().run()
2024-04-12T19:34:05.274315+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
2024-04-12T19:34:05.274370+00:00 app[web.1]: Arbiter(self).run()
2024-04-12T19:34:05.274381+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 229, in run
2024-04-12T19:34:05.274455+00:00 app[web.1]: self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
2024-04-12T19:34:05.274467+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 342, in halt
2024-04-12T19:34:05.274555+00:00 app[web.1]: self.stop()
2024-04-12T19:34:05.274559+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 396, in stop
2024-04-12T19:34:05.274642+00:00 app[web.1]: time.sleep(0.1)
2024-04-12T19:34:05.274653+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
2024-04-12T19:34:05.274729+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
2024-04-12T19:34:05.274739+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 530, in reap_workers
2024-04-12T19:34:05.274833+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2024-04-12T19:34:05.274883+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2024-04-12T19:34:05.360346+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2024-04-12T19:34:05.385735+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed

I already tried running
pip install gunicorn


Are you still having trouble with this?

You can't install things interactively (via pip install or similar) on Heroku. All dependencies must be declared so they can be installed at build time.
But that doesn't really matter, because you already have Gunicorn. It's referenced in several of the errors listed above, e.g. you're seeing a gunicorn.errors.HaltServer error.
The problem is your declared time zone:
ValueError: Incorrect timezone setting: America/Sao_paulo

The correct name for this time zone is America/Sao_Paulo, with a capital P. (I suspect that this may not be important on operating systems like Windows that have case-insensitive file systems. Heroku runs Linux, and like all sane operating systems, Linux cares about this stuff.)
Update your settings.py to fix the TIME_ZONE setting, commit, and redeploy.
